# javascript add/remove text in div when checkbox is unchecked/checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to learn the magic of **Javascript**.
What I am trying to do here is to **add** / **remove** text in div when **checkbox** is **unchecked** / **checked**.

This is me trying to do somekind of shopping cart:

```
function addCartItem(checkboxElement,cartElement,cartItemElement){

    var s = "";
    if(checkboxElement.checked == true){
        s = document.getElementById(cartItemElement).innerHTML += checkboxValue;
        updatePrice();
    }
    else{
        s = document.getElementById(cartItemElement).innerHTML = checkboxValue;
        s = s.replace(s,"");
        updatePrice();
   }
}
```

I cant get this to work, it wont remove the value from the unchecked checkbox.

**UPDATE**
I have this checkbox calling function like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="addCartItem(this,'cartElement','cartItemElement');" value="StarBreeze: TWD Demo |1337">
```

Comment: So your add is working but your remove isn't right?

Comment: what are you attaching this to OR who is calling this?

Comment: Are you passing in the checkboxElement as a string or as a DOM Element Object?

Comment: Made an update with how the HTML is looking for checkbox

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this

```
function addCartItem(checkboxElement,cartElement,cartItemElement){

    var s = document.getElementById(cartItemElement).innerHTML;
    if(checkboxElement.checked == true)
    {
        s += checkboxValue;
    }
    else
   {
        s = s.replace(checkboxValue,"");
   }
   document.getElementById(cartItemElement).innerHTML = s;
   updatePrice();
}
```

but I'm not sure where the checkbox value come from and what does it look like.

Comment: @alexandermogren you should mark this as answer so others can easily find it! :)

Answer (score 0):

On other way you can use jquery! jquery will make it too easy! Have a try! :)

```js
    $(function () {
        $("#yourCheckBox").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#showHideDiv").show();
            } else {
                $("#showHideDiv").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yourCheckBox" />
    Your Checkbox!
</label>
<hr />
<div id="showHideDiv" style="display: none">
    I am here!
</div>
```